How to fix wrongly ordered date axis in line chart
I am trying to build a line chart with a date axis to monitor the evolution of an indicator.
I built the data model with an auto date table, linked to the facts table through a date key. The model is working on other types of charts.
On this one however, I would like to visualize the weekly evolution of an aggregated value (sum of Memory used). From the facts table, I added a "Year-Week" column in the X axis, but all the values were not in chronological order.
I then tried to use the Date hierarchy variables in the X axis instead, but I had the same problem (see image).
In the table view, all rows are sorted by date ascending which is why I'm surprised by this result.
How do I fix this / go around it so that the dates are in a logical order?


Can you share some data ?

It looks like the columns are year and week.
You can try to sort by year and sort ascending to get the correct order.

